# Sort Array Using Custom Selector With Two Arguments

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of NSStrings but i'm unsure how to actually pass parameters into the @selector method. Here is why I'm trying to do

```
//After the optional: id like to pass a UITextField.text but not sure how.
NSArray *sortedSection = [wordSection sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sortValue:optional:)];
```

Here is the method I'm attempting to use.

```
- (NSComparisonResult) sortValue:(NSString *)otherString optional:(NSString *)otherLetters;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would this help?

```
NSArray *tm;
NSSortDescriptor *name = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *age = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES];
[tm sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:name, age, nil]];
```

didn't really understand what is in wordSection, what you like to sort and what will be in the UITextField.text